# Why my file gets deleted from /tmp directory on LINUX?

Tags: kerberos

(Linux Sles12 OS) After running command `kinit` to create a Kerberos ticket, I run `klist` and I see the file is stored at: `/tmp/krb5cc_123456789` its seems like after a random short time (few min/sec) the file gets deleted. how can I find what is responsible for the deletion of this file?

Thanks!

I searched and saw that the file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` is responsible for tmp deletion policy however it is with default setting means nothing gets deleted.

Comment: What's the ticket lifetime of that ticket? For a typical use case, ticket lifetime will be at least a couple of hours, but there is nothing stopping you from creating a ticket with a lifetime on the order of seconds.

Comment: so that's the thing, ticket experation is 10 hours but credentials file is deleted after few seconds.

Comment: Do you have root access to this system? Specifically, can you use either `fatrace` or `auditctl`?